# Django: get foreign key data to display in Angular

Tags: python, mysql, django, angular, foreign-keys

I am trying to retrieve all columns of a table through a foreign key relationship and am wondering how to do so. I have the following code:

**models.py**

```
class Athletes(models.Model):
    athlete_id = models.AutoField(db_column="AthleteID", primary_key="True")
    first_name = models.CharField(db_column='FirstName', max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(db_column='LastName', max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.athlete_id) + ' ' + self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Athletes'
        ordering = ('athlete_id', ) 

class VelocityLoadPredict(models.Model):
    vl_predict_id = models.AutoField(db_column="vl_predict_id", primary_key="True")
    athlete_id = models.ForeignKey(Athletes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="athleteID")
    lift_name = models.CharField(db_column="LiftName", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vl_predict_id) 

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'velocity_load_predict'
        ordering = ('vl_predict_id', )
```

And I am using serializers:

```
class AthletesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Athletes
        fields = ('athlete_id', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class VelocityLoadPredictSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VelocityLoadPredict
        fields = ('vl_predict_id', 'athlete_id', 'lift_name')
```

In Angular I have the following code (api.service):

**analytics.component.ts**

```
  analytics: Analytics[];  constructor(private data: DataService,
    private api: ApiService) {
      this.getAnalytics();
    }
        getAnalytics = () => {
    this.api.getAnalytics().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.analytics = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

I then want to represent the first name, last name and lift name in my html analytics file:

```
<p *ngFor='let element of analytics'>{{element.first_name}}</p>
```

How do I go about doing that when the Athletes table is linked through a foreign key of `athlete_id`?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

How to work with Angular to represent the athlete.first_name?

api.service.ts

```
  getVlPredict(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/velocityloadpredict/',
{headers: this.httpHeaders});
```

}

analytics.component.ts

```
    vlpredict: string[] = [];

  workoutCalls: string[] = ['first_name', 'lift_name'];
  workoutNames: string[] = ['First Name', 'Lift Name'];

    constructor(private data: DataService,
        private api: ApiService) {
          this.getVlPredict();
        }

          getVlPredict = () => {
            this.api.getVlPredict().subscribe(
              data => {
                this.vlpredict = data;
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              }
            );
          }
```

analytics.component.html

```
<div>
    <mat-table [dataSource]="vlpredict" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>   
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of workoutCalls; index as i">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{workoutNames[i]}}</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[column]}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="workoutCalls"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: workoutCalls"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub serializer` in your `VelocityLoadPredictSerializer`.

```
class VelocityLoadPredictSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    athlete = AthletesSerializer()  # this is sub serializer

    class Meta:
        model = VelocityLoadPredict
        fields = ('vl_predict_id', 'athlete_id', 'lift_name', 'athlete')
```

Then you can get this.

```
{
  "vl_predict_id": 1,
  "lift_name": "blabla",
  "athlete": {
    "athlete_id": 2,
    "first_name": "blabla",
    "last_name": "blabla"
  },
  ...
}
```

Or you want only `first_name`, you can use `source`

```
class VelocityLoadPredictSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='athlete.first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = VelocityLoadPredict
        fields = ('vl_predict_id', 'athlete_id', 'lift_name', 'first_name')
```

then,

```
{
  "vl_predict_id": 1,
  "lift_name": "blabla",
  "first_name": "blabla",
  ...
}
```

If you more info, see Django Rest Framework [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) and [relation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot. However, I receive an internal error in the console and the data disappears when attempting to display it in Angular using both of your proposed solutions; I use api.service to represent it the following way:  
getVlPredict(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/velocityloadpredict/',
    {headers: this.httpHeaders});
  }
And then call it in the component by subscribing. 
Any idea of where I should be changing the code to display the athlete.first_name in Angular?

Comment: You can edit your question. Don't leave the code in the comment. It's hard to read @Martina

Comment: Sorry about that (first time using Stack Overflow), I added the Angular side of it under "UPDATE".

Comment: `element` is `VelocityLoadPredict` serialized object. So you can `element.athlete[column]`. Check out the json example of my answer. @Martina